# Installing not-stable enough packages with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to install pubsubhubbub/php-subscriber in laravel 5.1. While installing, I am facing a problem listed below.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - The requested package pubsubhubub/subscriber could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
>     Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

I have no idea how to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be an issue with `minimum-stability` because that package has a stable release. I did notice however that it looks like there is a typo in the documentation and they have missed the last 'b' in 'hub', so it should be:

`"require" : {"pubsubhubbub/subscriber": "*"}`

or you can use:

`composer require pubsubhubbub/subscriber`

See: https://packagist.org/packages/pubsubhubbub/subscriber